# Incerease DPI resoultion for web page loaded into WebBrowser conriol in C#

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, display-dpi

We would like to display text and images of an web page in higher DPI for example take 300 DPI, but by default C# webbBrowser control uses 72/96 DPI which is currently system uses.

Is their any ways to setup the user defined DPI value to the webbBrowser control so that web page gets rendered in higher DPI value.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  Web browsers are designed for screen resolutions (72dpi).  If you need to print at higher resolutions, I suggest generating a PDF document.

Comment: Soviut thank you for your reply.

To get bitmap image of on loaded web page we have used IViewObject::Draw() interface method. and the draw method accept the Target DC as a parameter, can we specify higher DPI value in the Target Printer DC and pass it Draw method and get the desired High resolution Image.

Comment: IViewObject::Draw is for screen rendering. If the browser has scrollbar IViewObject::Draw would crop the output to what you see on screen and draw the scrollbar to the output. Is this expected by your customer?